# Unable to understand Recursivly calling same method with two different input

Tags: algorithm, recursion, data-structures, tree

I have recently started getting my hands on recursion. I have gone through some of the online documents available, but unable to understand how the recursion calls works when we call a same method with different inputs.

Just suppose, in case of tree i have seen

`return  find(node.left) + find(node.right);`

I am unable to understand how that works.

In general recursion every call gets a place in stack and when the base condition reaches we compute and return the result. 
I tried doing a small program where i called the same method from tow different caller with different index and if the base condition is reached, add the both returned value.

```
if(n==0){
        return arr[n];
    }

    else {
        return calculateSum(arr, n-1) + arr[n];
    }
```

The code works well. Now i moved forward and tried something like this.

And it is giving me **stack overflow**.

```
if(n==1){
        return arr[n];
    }

    else {
        return calculateSum(arr, n-1) + calculateSum(arr, n-2);
    }
```

I am completely unable to understand how it is happening, what am i missing out to from this topic to unable to understand it completely.

I have changes my code on based of suggestion provided. But unable to understand the flow. How the `n-2` is funtioning. I gave some print. Please find the print and Code below.

```
private static int calculateSum(int[] arr, int n, String caller){

    if(n<=1){
        System.out.println(caller+" : "+n+ " : "+arr[n]);

        return arr[n];
    }

    else {
        return calculateSum(arr, n-1," minus one") + calculateSum(arr, n-2,"minus two");
    }


}
```

**Prints :**

minus one : 1 : 2

minus two : 0 : 1

minus two : 1 : 2

minus one : 1 : 2

minus two : 0 : 1

minus one : 1 : 2

minus two : 0 : 1

minus two : 1 : 2

Sum of the array :13

If someone can help me to understand how it is working . I am wondering how the **minus two** value is *getting as 0 in the beginning and then as 1. and why **minus one** is been called again after minus two when once it has reached to attained the base condition.*

**Note :** I have removed the arr[n] with the return statement. so, for now i want to understand the calling and how it is working.

Comment: I would like to confirm whether if you change to `if (n <= 1)` would still cause the problem? I believe your recursion here doesn't actually end.

Comment: @NelsonYeung: That change will prevent the overflow, but now may try to access `arr[0]`.

Comment: @ScottHunter Why don't you want `arr[0]` anyway? I thought you want to some the whole array?

Comment: @NelsonYeung: The posted code (at least the final version) doesn't include it.

Comment: Posted the detailed of what happening in your code. Please check it may help you

Comment: I've update the latest code, unable to understand the execution flow. If someone can help.

Comment: @SanketSaha Please see my updated code at the end of my post and try to understand. It's Very easy now

Comment: @AdityaSrivastava Thanks for helping me with that, the code you have updated will return the sum of arr[n-1] and below elements, but i am looking for to understand how the two caller calling the same function works. Correct me if i am wrong to understand your code.

Comment: You have understood it correctly. Just here I am starting from last element and adding that last element value to the stack and moreover adding array of element except lastelement  to stack simultaneously. So array size decreases every time and sum increases . U got it probably now?

Comment: Your final program is still wrong; to verify, try it on the array [1,10,100,1000,10000].  If a description of your function were "Sum of arr [1..n]", then your recursive call is asking to compute "Sum of arr[1..n-1]"+"Sum of arr[1..n-2]", or "2 * (Sum of arr[1..n-2])+arr[n-1]", which is *not* what your original code did.

Comment: Actually. I am able to get the sum of the array. But I am trying to understand how the calling works. I have edited the description of my question and now I am trying to understand how the two caller calling same function with different inputs. I have also provided the prints. If anyone can help.

Answer (score 3):

Your last version of the program has a number of problems, not least of which is that the only element of the array ever included in the sum is `arr[1]`.

The reason for the stack overflow, however, is that it is possible to generate a call to `calculateSum` where the second argument is 0 (for example, the second recursive call when n==2), which will fail the base-case test and, because subsequent recursive calls have even smaller values for n, will never succeed.

The way I have found most helpful to think about recursion is imagine that someone else has written a function that solves your problem for "smaller" versions of that problem (for example, any sub-tree, or any smaller value of n; whatever is appropriate).  Write *your* function making use of that one, making sure that a) whenever you call it, it is with a smaller version of the problem, and b) if you have a small enough version of the problem that you can solve without a recursive call, don't make the recursive call.  (Note that, if you apply this technique to your final bit of code, you can see that, even if the recursive calls worked properly, you'd be double-counting most of the array.  And it is clear that your earlier version is correct.)

Here's the magic: by doing what I described above, you have written the very function that you assumed that someone else has written.

Comment: Corrected the code, but unable to understand how the call is been made, Updated the code with prints. If you can help me little further.

Comment: You have not corrected the code; you have only avoided the stack overflow, which is better, but not enough to make it correct.

Answer (score 0):

In this case you have not applied the correct base condition

See, your program:-

```
cal(arr,n){
if(n==1){
        return arr[n];
    }

    else {
        return calculateSum(arr, n-1) + calculateSum(arr, n-2);
    }

}
```

Take an example now,`arr = [1,2,3] n = 3`

```
Cal(arr,3){
// Base condtn fails
Recursion takes place now
cal(arr,2) + cal(arr,1);

}
```

Now, execute

```
cal(arr,2){
// Base condtn fails
Recursion takes place now
cal(arr,1) + cal(arr,0);
}
```

Now , execute

```
cal(arr,1){
// Base condtn true return arr[1]
}
```

Now, execute

```
cal(arr,0){
// Base condtn fails here also stackoverflow now never returning
}
```

Though sum can't be find out by this recursion, Use this

```
cal(arr, n)
{
    if (n <= 0)
        return 0;
    return (cal(a, n-1) + arr[n-1]);
}
```

Comment: This will never include any element whose index >= 1 in the sum.

Comment: Thanks. I've corrected the code now its is working . But unable to understand the call flow. I have given some print but unable to understand the call flow. 
Note : I have change the condition to (n<2)

**minus one : 1 : 2
minus two : 0 : 1
minus two : 1 : 2
 minus one : 1 : 2
minus two : 0 : 1
 minus one : 1 : 2
minus two : 0 : 1
minus two : 1 : 2
Sum of the array :13**

Comment: @SanketSaha Glad to help you. Always try with the short example if you stuck anywhere in recursion

Comment: `if(n<1) { return arr[n] }` will never return an element from `arr` whose index is >= 1; as this is the only part of the code the extracts a value from `arr` directly, that applies to the whole function.

Comment: @SanketSaha Use some short examples. It will help you sort out the problem